# Get list of running applications (translate from Applescript?)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, applescript

I want to monitor what applications are running. It's simple enough in AppleScript, but I can't find any useful information about how to do the same thing in Objective-C.

```
on run
tell application "System Events" to get name of every process
end run
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first port of call is the [NSWorkspace](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html) documentation. In particular the `runningApplications` method.